# Take attributes from other layer in ATLAS from QGIS

Tags: qgis, atlas

I am performing an ATLAS where I have a table and I would like to use data from other layer. I have seen that joining them into QGIS allows me to select the fields from the second layer but the problem is that for one record in parent layer I'd need to list two or more records for the child layer (sharing them the ID) but the system take only the first record. Is there any way I can solve this?

Parent layer:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

child layer:

```
ID
1
1 (the system doesnt take this one)
2
2 (The system doesnt take this one)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is called in database speak a 1-to-Many relationship. This cannot be represented in a join as joins are 1-to-1 relationships. That's why when you create a join in QGIS, the fields from the joined layer are added to the origin layer because for every row in the origin table there is one and only one row in the destination table. This is not the case in a 1-to-Many relationship where for each row in the origin table you may have more than one row in the joined table. Fitting all this data in a single table would break one of the rules of databases which requires that one entity doesn't exist more than once in a table.

Long story short, what you can do in QGIS is create a relation which you can access in the project properties. In this case, for each feature in the origin table, you will be able to see the related rows but in a separate window when using the identify tool and not in a single table row.

(I'm using my phone so no screenshots possible)

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and i get to visualize the data doing a relation in the project properties and then changing the attribute table view from singe table to diferent windows, the question us more, how can i do in ATLAS to make, as example, a PDF for a single ID and another box with a list of the other field which belongs to this ID.

Comment: Could you edit the question to add a figure, even if drawn by hand of what you want the result to be? I'm quite a visual person and a picture is worth a thousand words!

Comment: Yes, of course, I have already uploaded. Sorry for the typos :) and thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not aware of any direct way of achieving what you want, whether  through built in functionality or plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

just wanna tell you that I have already solved this problem. First of all and as #Techie_Gus commented in the first post, a RELATION between both layers has to be created under the Project Properties. Once the relation is created, in ATLAS we can add an attribute table from the child layer and go to its properties and select the SOURCE as "Relationship child" and the relation that we have created underneath:

[image]